# What does "residt" mean in Power Regression?

Tags: regression

In class, we would run power regression for sets of data points to find variation equations. The power regression takes a set of points and fits it to the model $$\hat{y}=ax^b $$

When doing it on the calculator (TI 89 Titanium if that matters) after it does the regression, it lists two more sets of values into the table: residt and resid.

I am familiar with what the "resid" represents: the residuals, or the error between predicted and actual y-values.

However, I am not sure what the "residt" could represent. One thought was that it may have been standardized residuals, but then I noticed it doesn't show up whenever I do a simple linear regression, so I am not so sure.

Thanks for any help or clarification given

Comment: They are probably "studentized" residuals since Student (Gosset) was known for his "T" distribution.

Comment: @AdamO No. Searching the [TI-89 manual](http://facstaff.cbu.edu/wschrein/media/Stat/statsle.pdf), "Residuals associated with the linear fit of the transformed data are calculated and placed in the residt list."

Comment: @Matthew Gunn That makes sense. So they are the residuals that go along with performing a linear transformation first then simply running a linear regression of the transformed data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching Google for the [TI-89 manual](http://facstaff.cbu.edu/wschrein/media/Stat/statsle.pdf) I find,

> Values for $a$, $b$, $r^2$ , and $r$ are displayed in the `PowerReg` output
>   dialog box. The power regression equation is stored in `Y1`. Residuals
>   for the power regression are calculated and placed in the resid list.
>   The previous contents of `resid` are overwritten by the new data.
>   Residuals associated with the linear fit of the transformed data are
>   calculated and placed in the `residt` list.

Reading between the lines, my interpretation/guess is that `residt` would be residuals from the ordinary least squares regression:

$$\log y_i = \log a + b \log x_i + \epsilon_i$$

I'm not 100% sure though. You could easily check if that's indeed correct.

Comment: Doing a simple test with random points confirmed this! Thank you